# Perl Code Security Scanner Other than RATS? (MUST BE _STATIC_)

Tags: perl, security, graph, code-analysis

Other than [RATS](http://www.fortify.com/security-resources/rats.jsp), are there any other Perl security scanners?

Possibly also any *STATIC* only [perl code graph](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=25807) engine which has an ability to follow data-flow or otherwise tainted input?

Answer (score 3):

[Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/~elliotjs/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic.pm) implements a number of security checks largely based upon the book *Perl Best Practices*. Given that Perl::Critic is written using the PPI parser, it probably can achieve much greater introspection than RATS can.

That said, no code scanner or utility is going to find security errors that are the result of just poor programming practices. A few simple best practices can go a long way. The [perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) manpage goes into detail about many Perl security issues, and has some good practical advice.

From my own experience auditing mountains of bad code:

- Always use taint mode (`-T` flag)
- Always `use strict`
- Always `use warnings`
- Always use [placeholders](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7548) in DBI code
- Always scrutinize and sanitize any input before using it as a filename, method/function name, or argument to a system call
- Avoid string `eval` whenever possible; it's inefficient, anyway. Never put user input into an `eval` string.

I'm sure there's more that I'm not remembering at the moment, but it's late. :)

Comment: It doesn't really implement security checks because it has no idea what any of the code is actually doing. It can, however, tell you about questionable code locally. It can't tell you anything about what will happen when you run the code, however.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to a graph engine, I just found [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/PPI-1.201/lib/PPI.pm)

---

> Parse, Analyze and Manipulate Perl
>   (without perl)

---

Key features include;

---

1. Documentation (of perl code)
2. Structural and Quality Analysis
3. Refactoring
4. Layout
5. Presentation